# how to inject a value in an angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to get a defined value injected into a controller. I have gone through the angular docs and many other blogs too - but obviously I have messed up something critical here.

```
myapp = angular.module('MYAPP', ['ngRoute'])
.run(function () {
    console.info("Hello MYAPP");
});
myapp.value("vx1", "placeholder for vx1");
```

and in controller

```
myapp.controller("MainCtlr", ["vx1", "ovEnv", function($scope, $timeout, vx1, ovEnv){
    console.info("ctor MainCtlr env=", ovEnv, "; vx1=", vx1);
    ...
```

But I always get `undefined` for `vx1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`["vx1", "ovEnv", function($scope, $timeout, vx1, ovEnv){`

These two sequences need to be equal. What happens if you remove the `["..]` array part and just leave `function(...) {`?

Like this:
`myapp.controller("MainCtlr", function($scope, $timeout, vx1, ovEnv) { ... })`

or
`["$scope", "$timeout", "vx1", "ovEnv", function($scope, $timeout, vx1, ovEnv)` (see comment)

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

> **Inline Array Annotation**
>
> This is the preferred way to annotate
>   application components. This is how the examples in the documentation
>   are written.
>
> For example:
>
> `someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter',
>   function($scope, greeter) {   // ... }]);`

Comment: Or ` ["$scope", "$timeout", "vx1", "ovEnv", function($scope, $timeout, vx1, ovEnv)`